# Variable not changing in Java

Tags: java, swing, variables

I'm have made a calculator using a swing window. I have four buttons for each operator, i.e. addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
//Components
String op, ans;
int num2, num1, num3;
//Buttons
JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
JButton b9 = new JButton("9");
JButton b0 = new JButton("0");
JButton clr = new JButton("C");
JButton eqs = new JButton("=");
JButton op1 = new JButton("+");
JButton op2 = new JButton("-");
JButton op3 = new JButton("*");
JButton op4 = new JButton("/");
//Content Pane
Container contentPane = getContentPane();
//Text Field
JTextArea txt = new JTextArea(1, 20);
//Panels
JPanel opr = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
JPanel num = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,3));
//Constructor
public Calculator()
{
    super("Calculator");
    setSize(500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(pnl);
    add(num);
    //adding text field
    pnl.add(txt);
    //adding numpad
    num.add(b1);
    num.add(b2);
    num.add(b3);
    num.add(b4);
    num.add(b5);
    num.add(b6);
    num.add(b7);
    num.add(b8);
    num.add(b9);
    num.add(clr);
    num.add(b0);
    num.add(eqs);
    //adding operation buttons
    opr.add(op1);
    opr.add(op2);
    opr.add(op3);
    opr.add(op4);
    //adding contentpane
    contentPane.add("North",pnl);
    contentPane.add("Center",num);
    contentPane.add("East",opr);
    //adding actionlistener
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    b4.addActionListener(this);
    b5.addActionListener(this);
    b6.addActionListener(this);
    b7.addActionListener(this);
    b8.addActionListener(this);
    b9.addActionListener(this);
    b0.addActionListener(this);
    op1.addActionListener(this);
    op2.addActionListener(this);
    op3.addActionListener(this);
    op4.addActionListener(this);
    clr.addActionListener(this);
    eqs.addActionListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
}
//event handler method
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource() == b1)
        txt.append("1");
    if (e.getSource() == b2)
        txt.append("2");
    if (e.getSource() == b3)
        txt.append("3");
    if (e.getSource() == b4)
        txt.append("4");
    if (e.getSource() == b5)
        txt.append("5");
    if (e.getSource() == b6)
        txt.append("6");
    if (e.getSource() == b7)
        txt.append("7");
    if (e.getSource() == b8)
        txt.append("8");
    if (e.getSource() == b9)
        txt.append("9");
    if (e.getSource() == b0)
        txt.append("0");
    if (e.getSource() == clr)
        txt.setText("");
    if (e.getSource() == op1)
    {
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());
        txt.setText("");
        op = "add";
    }
    if (e.getSource() == op2)
    {
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());
        txt.setText("");
        op = "sub";
    }
    if (e.getSource() == op3)
    {
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());
        txt.setText("");
        op = "mul";
    }
    if (e.getSource() == op4)
    {
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());
        txt.setText("");
        op = "div";
    }
    if (e.getSource() == eqs)
    {
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());
        switch (op)
        {
        case "add":
            num3 = num1 + num2;
            break;
        case "sub":
            num3 = num1 - num2;
            break;
        case "mul":
            num3 = num1 * num2;
            break;
        case "div":
            num3 = num1 / num2;
            break;
        default:
            txt.setText("Please enter an integer");
        }
        ans = Integer.toString(num3);
        txt.setText(ans);
    }
}
//main method
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
}
```

}

When I click on an operator button and do not enter an integer, and click on an operator again, a list of errors appear on the command prompt. The Calculator works fine but I don't want those errors coming up. I think it's because of the 'op' variable not changing.

Comment: Add a conditional to ignore it or wrap it in a try-catch.

Comment: What do you want it to do when you click an operator and the field contains something that is not an integer?

Comment: 'Please enter an integer' should appear.

Comment: Could you please post the error logs?

Comment: I can't copy them from the command prompt.

Comment: You didn't paste the complete code. When I run the program that you've pasted, I only see the 5 calculator buttons, I do not see the JTextArea txt. Also, variable eqs is defined twice. Could you please paste the complete code?

Comment: The complete code. Sorry it took time, my browser is hangs a bit.

Comment: Please don't modify your code while answers are going on.

Comment: Have you heard about arrays or Lists? This is rather clumsy code.

Comment: I'm just a beginner. Yes, I know about arrays and lists but they have a really large amount of errors so I prefer to keep things easy. When I'm sure I can use arrays and lists without error and suff, I will use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a calculator that performs actions on data when you press a button. Correct, but you should realize that the action doesn't make sense if the user hasn't entered a number before demanding the next operation. To make sure that another operand has been entered, add (in two places) a statement like

```
if( txt.getText().matches( "-?\\d+" ) ){
    // proceed, a valid number has been entered
    ...
}
```

Also, take care:

```
case "div":
        num3 = num1 / num2;
        break;
```

This throws a nasty error if num2 happens to be zero - even computers cannot divide by zero, as mathematics forbids it in simple arithmetic. Again, insert another if statement to catch this situation.

```
List<JButton> digits = new ArrayList<>();
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    JButton b = new JButton( "" + i );
    digits.add( b );
    num.add( b );
}

// in actionPerformed
int dig = digits.indexOf( e );
if( dig >= 0 ){
    txt.append( dig );
}
```

Comment: what does `.matches( "-?\\d+" )` do?

Comment: This is a regular expression match: it returns true if the string contains '-' or not, and then one or more digits. Have some fun and learn: http://regexcrossword.com/

Answer (score -4):

Its a null reference error you need to have the variables to be equal to something or it will through the error.

Comment: Couldn't understand. I'm just 13 years old.

Comment: int num2 = 0, num1 = 0, num3= 0; try that

Comment: If that doesn't then send me a screenshot of the error.

Comment: @Max an int can never cause a NPE, so please don't confuse others.